# Aurelia doesn't build after installing jspm

Tags: aurelia, jspm

I followed the tutorial on aurelia website to install aurelia-cli. Everything works fine.

Under src folder, I did `npm install jspm` and the project no longer builds.

```
[Error running Gulp]
```

I tried to add gulpfile.js but doesn't work.
Any idea what caused all these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that aurelia-cli and jspm aren't compatible at this time.

Either I build on aurelia-skeleton and install jspm or no jspm with aurelia-cli.